# Storing thrift-serialized objects on disk

Tags: scala, serialization, binary, thrift

## Requirements

- I need to store a stream of Thrift-serialized objects in a file in such a way that I can read the file later on and obtain the deserialized objects.
- The objects could be of different types.

## Questions

(i) What's the best way to delimit each object in the file. For example, in a text file, I could separate each object with a newline character. Is that approach valid for binary files as well?

(ii) To mark the type of each object (to be used during deserialization), I'm planning to add a type field at the beginning of each byte sequence. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important question is how you plan to access the file: Sequential or random access?

## Sequential access (sort of) or few data

> What's the best way to delimit each object in the file. For example, in a text file, I could separate each object with a newline character. Is that approach valid for binary files as well?

Obviously not ;-). But don't worry, there is a better solution. To store a list of data, one can simply and literally store a `list<data>`. In other words, something like this:

```
struct foo { 1: string field, 2: i32 otherfield }

list<foo>
```

If the data are not only `foo`, but of varying types, put a union in between:

```
struct foo { 1: string field, 2: i32 otherfield }

struct bar { 1: map<string,wtf> seinfield, 2: double cloverfield }

struct wtf { 1: list<double> even_more_fields }

union MyDataRecord {
  1: foo foo
  2: bar bar
  3: wtf wtf
}

list<MyDataRecord>
```

Because we still read and write everything at once, there is no need for artifical limitors.

> To mark the type of each object (to be used during deserialization), I'm planning to add a type field at the beginning of each byte sequence. Is there a better approach?

If you put the data into a `list<>` like outlined above, Thrift takes care about it. You just read and write the entire list as a whole.

## Random access and/or lots of data

Things will change dramatically, if you want random access to your data. The problem with this is, that - in order to get it efficient and fast - you need to somehow determine the position of a given element in the file **without always scanning the entire file first**<sup>1)</sup>. In most cases, the byte size of the entries written will vary. Even if all of them are of one type `foo` only, one still cannot assume that a certain element is located at

```
position = sizeof(foo) *  index_of_desired_element
```

because `foo` has a variable sized data member: the `string` field.

To solve that issue, we basically have two options.

**(1) Fixed-size records**: We could make sure that all elements do not exceed a predefined maximum size, and use that as the file record size. We also do no longer use a `list<>`, instead we write our data at the right positions in the file. The position of the n-th element is than again

```
position = N * predefined_record_size
```

The downside is obviously that we potentially waste a lot of space, plus the limited size of data.

**(2) Index file**: Second option is to maintain a separate index file, which holds the position of each entry in the data file. This, again could be a simple list of integers:

```
list<i32>
```

The downside here is, that you need to make sure the index is in proper shape, especially on insert, delete and update operations in the middle of the file.

The more general problem with both options above is, that especially insert and delete operations may become painful, because you may have to move a lot of data around. To handle that, you will find yourself adding more gimmicks such as delete markers or the like to the solution.

## Bottom line

If you have only a bunch of data, the `list<union>` approach could be what you are looking for. Because the `union` is extendable at any time, the solution is also ready for other elements to be added later.

If you absolutely want to access the data sequentially only, either choose the `list<union>` approach, or read/write the `union` elements one by one. Thrift supports a `Skip()` function that allows to skip over unwanted data, if that is needed.

If, however, you want to access the data randomly and/or have lot of data to handle, a real database may be more suitable.

---

<sup>1)</sup> Scanning a potentially large file for record delimiters is not [the kind of O(?) you want](http://bigocheatsheet.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My use case is sequential access. However, instead of maintaining an index file, I think it would be better to store the sizes of the records along with the records. For example, the first 4 bytes of every record would indicate the number of bytes that constitute the record (assuming no record is bigger than 4GB). This way, absolute offsets needn't be stored and would also make insertion/deletion easier.

Comment: Just assume your data file spans several GB and ask yourself, whether searching, inserting or deleting an entry at index `15.883.127` of `124.657.013` records is really an `O(1) task` or at least `O(logN)` using that algorithm? Remember that **almost all algorithms are fast if you have only 10 data items.**.

Comment: If you still want to do it, look at `TFramedProtocol`. It does exactly that and writes the size of the data frame to follow as i32 into the output stream.

Comment: Of course, insertion and deletion would be an expensive operation in this case. However, as I mentioned earlier, my use case is just sequential access and it always starts from index 0, ie, the beginning of the file. And in that case, every access is O(1).